# Uniqueness of minimum of $x^Tx$ over $Ax=b$

Tags: vector-spaces

To Minimize $x^Tx$ over $Ax=b$, I first expressed $x$ as $x_0+t$ where $x_0\in N(A)^\perp$ and $Ax_0=b$ and $t\in N(A)$
Thus, I need to minimize $||x_0+t||^2$ over $At=0$ but since $x_0.t=0, ||x_0+t||^2=||x_0||^2+||t||^2$ and hence the minimum value is at $t=0$ and it is $||x_0||^2$

But how do I know that $x_0$ is solely dependent on $A$ and $b$. Can the final answer be expressed as a function of $A,b$ only? Note that $A$ need not be invertible. Also, if $\exists x_1$ st $Ax_1=b$ and $x_1\in N(A)^\perp$, then is is true that $x_1 = x_0$? (If this is true then also my problem is solved)

Comment: You could use Lagrange multipliers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider if $x_0, x_1\in N(A)^\perp$ are such that $Ax_0 = Ax_1 = b$. Then in particular we have
$$
Ax_0 - Ax_1 = 0
$$
which by definition gives $x_0-x_1\in N(A)$.

So $x_0-x_1$ is in both $N(A)$ and in $N(A)^\perp$, and it must therefore be $0$. This solves your problem (as soon as you have proven that such an $x_0$ actually exists, of course).

Comment: This does show uniqueness. But is it possible to express $x_0^Tx_0$ is terms of only $A,b$?

Comment: @Anvit You have done that when you say that "$x_0$ is such that $Ax_0 = b$ and $x_0\in N(A)^\perp$".

Comment: But can I do it explicity? For example if $Ax=b$ then $Gb$ is one of the solutions for $x$ where $G$ is the generalized inverse ($G$ is not unique). With the added condition of $x_0 \in N(A)^\perp$, how does $G$ change?

Comment: @Anvit My immediate suspicion is that $G$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse. But I'll have to look into that.

Comment: I might have the name wrong but, $G$ was defined as $Q^{-1}P^{-1}$ where $A=PQ$ is the rank factorization. $GAG = G, AGA = A$. $P^{-1}$ is the left inverse and $ Q^{-1}$ is the right inverse.